# HTML working calendar

Tags: javascript, html, calendar

i've created a website with a date-picker calender

But the calendar is hardcoded as 365 divs with 365 div IDs and text inside.
How do i make a "real" calender that works* and then i can style it to look and behave (with javascript) like the one i've simulated (created with divs) ? :) Now it is created like:

```
<div id = "calender">
    <div id = "january1"> 1 </div>
    <div id = "january2"> 1 </div>
    ...
</div>
```

I want a real calendar which generates the right amount of days in a month for all years...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the purpose of your website? For any dynamic content you'll probably want to look at some background frameworks with processing abilities, such as Ruby on Rails, Django, Node.js or even PHP(not recommended though), to create a fully functional dynamic website. Of course you can also present a boilerplate page to the client first, before dynamically altering the divs with Javascript on client side. But that doesn't make much sense.

A starting point for Rails would be https://www.railstutorial.org/book, which doesn't only explain Rails but also does a decent job guiding you through the whole basic web development process.

Comment: The purpose is "simply" to have a calender that i can fully style in CSS and make hover and clickEvents on each date with javascript. The dates, months and years must be correct. Unfortunately i only knows html, css, javascript and a little php at the moment... But i will do some research on if Ruby, Django or Node.js can solve my problem. :)

Comment: maybe something like https://www.softcomplex.com/products/tigra_calendar/ can be used?

Comment: That "product" seem to only offer a calendar for the "date" type of field in forms, which basically already has a date pop-up on its own. If you want to render some div customized by yourself with logic, as stated in your question, then a *template engine* has to be used, such as HAML of rails http://haml.info/ or Jinja2 for Django. You can read their descriptions to get a feeling what they can achieve. And anyways, if your website doesn't have any backend logic, then what's the point of letting the user select something anyways :)

Comment: The selected is to be used in a sql database :) ill look at the engines you posted, thanks.

Comment: @CasperTraberg-Larsen Still your database would need some kind of interface/logic to interact with your web page, right? Otherwise how can you actually commit the data in your database anyways. And by the way, if you find my answer and comments useful, you can upvote, and/or accept it as an answer to your question.

Comment: I query the db with php.. Ill guess it is not possible for my skills to make the costum calendar

Comment: If you have PHP in your backend, you can actually also produce custom div in PHP. The simplest idea would be to use a for loop and increment a count for each go, and use `echo` to produce the div. For examples see http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php and http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp That means your page will be produced by php instead of pure HTML.